# Getting a System.Exception: APPLICATION NOT LICENSED in my application

Tags: .net

Hi I am getting the following exception when entering a URL

```
APPLICATION: Not Licensed. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Exception: APPLICATION: Not Licensed.

Source Error: 


An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.


Stack Trace: 


[Exception: APPLICATION: Not Licensed.]
   Application.Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e) +112
   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +148
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +75
```

This is the URL
http://ticketsystem./Home/ConfirmAttendance/34915?vt=635xj1hogLSgWWALEfaKJ3cM3uo%3D

Even if the ticket or vt parameter is not valid, shouldn't they be getting a more specific exception like "id invalid or vt code invalid?"

what is this error ? I have never seen it before.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: `ticketsystem.` does not look like a valid domain name.

Comment: Are you using a third-party application or component? It sounds like it's looking for a license key and not finding one.